# Qualtrics loop and merge based on items presented in previous loop

Tags: qualtrics

I am trying to create a survey where participants are:

1. Presented with 20 randomly selected images from a set of 30 images and asked a question about each image.
2. Presented with 10 randomly selected images from the set of 20 that was presented in question 1.

I am using loop and merge for the first step (choosing "present only 20 of total loops"). However, I am wondering if I can rely on what was presented in the first question for the second loop and merge. Or maybe there's an easier way of thinking about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use loop based on a question for your two loops.

(1) Set up a MC question with your 30 images as choices.  Use Advanced Randomization to randomly display 20.  Hide the question with JavaScript.  Base your first loop on the displayed choices in this question.

(2) Set up a second MC question where you carryover the displayed options from the first MC question as the choices.  Use Advanced Randomization to randomly display 10. Hide the question with JavaScript.  Base your second loop on the displayed choices in this question.